# Is there a way to import a stylesheet and prepend a class to it?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have a `vendor.scss` file which includes some 3rd-party libraries. These libraries I only want to have an effect on certain parts of the website.

I am looking for a solution similar to this if possible:

```
#my-app {
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; 
}
```

because refactoring it and pulling in the libraries manually would be too time-consuming at this point.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: it should be possible as is... Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks @smnbbrv . Completely my bad. I imported `@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";` inside the block as well and it broke. Interesting.